# Separar conteúdo de uma coluna em outras colunas

Tags: r

Tenho um arquivo em forma de tabela. Preciso separar o conteúdo de uma coluna específica em outras colunas, os dados são separados por `;`.

Bem eu consegui fazer isto, mas o problema é que o conteúdo resultará para cada linha um número diferente de colunas. E por este código ele replica até o conteúdo até atingir o número de colunas. Eu queria que ele exibisse *NA*.

Pelo meu código obtenho isto:

```
  v1      v2      v3    p/sep  sep sep  sep sep  
dados1  dados2  dados3  a;b;c   a   b   c   a  
dados1  dados2  dados3  a;c     a   c   a   c  
dados1  dados2  dados3  a       a   a   a   a  
dados1  dados2  dados3  a;b     a   b   a   b  
dados1  dados2  dados3  a;b;c;d a   b   c   d  
dados1  dados2  dados3  a;b     a   b   a   b
```

Mas o resultado que espero ter é:

```
  v1      v2      v3 separar  sep sep   sep sep  
dados1  dados2  dados3  a;b;c   a   b   c   NA  
dados1  dados2  dados3  a;c     a   c   a   c  
dados1  dados2  dados3  a       a   NA  NA  NA  
dados1  dados2  dados3  a;b     a   b   NA  NA  
dados1  dados2  dados3  a;b;c;d a   b   c   d  
dados1  dados2  dados3  a;b     a   b   NA  NA  

library(reshape)        
file_split = data.frame(file,colsplit(file$separar,split=";",names="buffer",))
```

Comment: Na segunda linha da resposta esperada é realmente "a c a c" ou "a c NA NA"

Comment: Tem outro erro no código, não existe a vírgula depois de `"buffer"`, e também esse argumento não tem muito sentido pois define um nome de coluna, sendo que 4 são criadas. Não que seja um grande problema neste caso, mas o ideal é colocar o código exato e o output exato gerados, aparentemente você editou algumas coisas à mão.

Comment: 'buffer" foi um erro de sintaxe, achei que ele repetiria o nome buffer como cabeçalho de todas as colunas novas @Molx

Comment: foi erro de digitação @MarcosBanik

Comment: @JoyceMaia se quiser usar "buffer", você precisa diferenciar as colunas de algum jeito, pois colunas com nomes iguais não são uma boa ideia. Uma forma de fazer isso é usar `paste` como eu fiz na minha resposta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A maior dificuldade é fornecer nomes para as novas colunas. Vou adotar a mesma variável `file` e o mesmo esquema para os nomes das colunas que o Molx utilizou.

Caso saiba de antemão o número de colunas contido em `separar`. (4, nesse caso)

```
colunas <- paste0("sep", 1:4)
```

O número de colunas pode ser obtido por meio da função `str_count` do pacote `stringr`.

```
library(stringr);
colunas <- paste0("sep", 1:(max(str_count(file$separar, ';')) + 1));
```

Agora é possível dividir a coluna `separar` utilizando a função `separate` do pacote `tidry`.

```
library(tidyr);
separate(file, separar, into = colunas, sep = ';', remove = FALSE,
         extra = "merge");
```

Answer (score 4):

Você esteve muito próxima da solução. Se ao invés do `reshape` utilizar o `reshape2`, utilizando a mesma função (trocando o argumento `split` por `pattern`), você chega próxima do que gostaria:

```
> file <- read.table(text="  v1      v2      v3    separar  sep sep  sep sep  
dados1  dados2  dados3  a;b;c   a   b   c   a  
dados1  dados2  dados3  a;c     a   c   a   c  
dados1  dados2  dados3  a       a   a   a   a  
dados1  dados2  dados3  a;b     a   b   a   b  
dados1  dados2  dados3  a;b;c;d a   b   c   d  
dados1  dados2  dados3  a;b     a   b   a   b", header=T, as.is=T)[,1:4]
> library(reshape2)        
> file_split = data.frame(file, colsplit(file$separar, pattern=";", names=paste0("sep", 1:4)))
```

Resultando em

```
> file_split
      v1     v2     v3 separar sep1 sep2 sep3 sep4
1 dados1 dados2 dados3   a;b;c    a    b    c     
2 dados1 dados2 dados3     a;c    a    c          
3 dados1 dados2 dados3       a    a               
4 dados1 dados2 dados3     a;b    a    b          
5 dados1 dados2 dados3 a;b;c;d    a    b    c    d
6 dados1 dados2 dados3     a;b    a    b
```

Isso é uma questão de definição padrão da função. Em ambos pacotes, não é possível controlar o comportamento para número de colunas diferentes, mas o `reshape` usa reciclagem, enquanto o `reshape2`completa com strings vazias. Para substituir os espaços vazios por NA, você pode fazer, por exemplo:

```
> file_split[file_split == ""] <- NA
> file_split
      v1     v2     v3 separar sep1 sep2 sep3 sep4
1 dados1 dados2 dados3   a;b;c    a    b    c <NA>
2 dados1 dados2 dados3     a;c    a    c <NA> <NA>
3 dados1 dados2 dados3       a    a <NA> <NA> <NA>
4 dados1 dados2 dados3     a;b    a    b <NA> <NA>
5 dados1 dados2 dados3 a;b;c;d    a    b    c    d
6 dados1 dados2 dados3     a;b    a    b <NA> <NA>
```

Só é importante tomar cuidado aqui pois essa substituição troca todos os valores `""` da tabela, talvez seja mais seguro usar os nomes/índices das colunas para não correr o risco de alterar outros dados que deveriam se manter vazios e não NA (se houver).

---

Antes de achar essa diferença do `reshape2` eu fiz uma alternativa usando base e seguindo [essa dica](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15201690/724200). Não é tão sucinta, mas já que está pronta, segue abaixo:

```
> file.split <- strsplit(file$separar, ";")
> n.obs <- sapply(file.split, length)
> seq.max <- seq_len(max(n.obs))
> resultado <- cbind(file, t(sapply(file.split, "[", i = seq.max)))
> resultado
      v1     v2     v3 separar 1    2    3    4
1 dados1 dados2 dados3   a;b;c a    b    c <NA>
2 dados1 dados2 dados3     a;c a    c <NA> <NA>
3 dados1 dados2 dados3       a a <NA> <NA> <NA>
4 dados1 dados2 dados3     a;b a    b <NA> <NA>
5 dados1 dados2 dados3 a;b;c;d a    b    c    d
6 dados1 dados2 dados3     a;b a    b <NA> <NA>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
library(reshape)        
file_split = data.frame(file,colsplit(file$separar,split=";",names="buffer",))
```

Para colocar nome nas duas colunas precisa alterar o final `names = c("Buffer", "Buffer2"))`

Ou seja, fica assim

```
library(reshape)        
file_split = data.frame(file,colsplit(file$separar,split=";",names= c("buffer","Buffer2")))
```